# Gettin Array of Inputs from User in Python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, input

I want to get an array of inputs from user in command prompt not 1by1 for example in the command line there should be something like this,

> Documents>Projects>python myProject.py "2 4 6 8"

That "2 4 6 8" Part should be in array in my project. Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? This is not a homwework solver site. It would be good for us to know what have worked on, to give a better solution.

It seems like you want to get `2 4 6 8` into a list. You can pass it as `python myProject.py 2 4 6 8` on the command line. In your `myProject.py` use:

```
import sys

s = sys.argv[1:]
print(s)
```

This will print `['2','4','6','8']`. This is a list of characters. If you want a list of integers, you can use list comprehension like:

`list_of_ints = [int(i) for i in s]`

This will insert your command line characters to a list of ints.

Do read about command line arguments and research/google your question because it might be already answered.